# F# -> EF generating wrong sql

Tags: entity-framework, f#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to do a simple many-to-one relationship in EF and have defined it like:

```
type Car() =
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable private id : int
    member x.ID with get() = x.id and set(v) = x.id <- v
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable private carName : string
    member x.CarName with get() = x.carName and set(v) = x.carName <- v
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable private dealer : Dealer
    member x.Dealer with get() = x.dealer and set(v) = x.dealer <- v

and Dealer() =
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable private id : int
    member x.ID with get() = x.id and set(v) = x.id <- v
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable private name : string
    member x.Name with get() = x.name and set(v) = x.name <- v
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable private cars : seq<Car>
    member x.Cars with get() = x.cars and set(v) = x.cars <- v

type MyContext() = 
    inherit DbContext("MyContext")
    [<DefaultValue(true)>] val mutable private cars : DbSet<Car>
    member x.Cars with get() = x.cars and set(v) = x.cars <- v
    [<DefaultValue(true)>] val mutable private dealers : DbSet<Dealer>
    member x.Dealers with get() = x.dealers and set(v) = x.dealers <- v
```

and calling it the following way in the console start:

```
let ctx = new MyContext()
Query.query <@ seq { for x in ctx.Cars do if x.CarName = "Volvo" then yield x.Dealer.Name } @>
```

the above will generate the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM  [dbo].[Cars] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Dealers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Dealer_ID] = [Extent2].[ID]
WHERE N'Volvo' = [Extent1].[CarName]
```

Now is my question, why do it take the Dealer defined in the Car type and translate it to `Dealer_ID` instead of `DealerID?`

Comment: What column do you have in your Car table? DealerID or Dealer_ID? How did you create the table?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - In my `Car` table the column that refers to `Dealer` is named `DealerID` - I've created the table myself (not generated)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an F# specific problem. (F# quotations are just translated to C#-style expression trees and the expression tree contains MemberInfo of the property, so it cannot contain an incorrect name).

Comment: It is problem of missing mapping. If you create table and use your own column name for foreign key you must explicitly map it in `OnModelCreating`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the explicit mapping for this property using either the [StoreName DataAnnotation attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx) or the [Fluent mapping HasColumnName method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx).